# Suppress passthrough of click outside pop-up menu

Tags: delphi, vcl, popupmenu

A button's `OnClick` handler displays a `TPopupMenu` when the button is clicked. Clicking the button again when the menu is visible causes the pop-up first to be cancelled due to the click outside the pop-up area (good), but then for the menu to pop up a second time due to the button's `OnClick` handler being invoked (bad).

Nothing fancy here:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  posn : TPoint;
begin
  posn := Button1.ClientToScreen(Point(Button1.Width, Button1.Height));
  PopupMenu1.Popup(posn.X, posn.Y);
end;
```

My question is this: how can I stop the pop-up reappearing like this when the button is clicked to cancel it?

**Edit**

Alternatively, is there a better choice than TButton for the button, that avoids the problem? I know about the split button style - but the correct usage for this is the left side executes the default action and the right side with the down-triangle drops down a menu - but I don't want a default action, the button to be split, or the down-triangle symbol.

---

This is what I've already tried:

1. Disable the button just before calling `PopupMenu1.Popup()`, and enable it immediately after. Doesn't work because the pass-through click event isn't unqueued until the `OnClick` handler has exited. (Also the button changes appearance.)
2. (As above but using `TPopupActionBar` instead of `TPopupMenu` - in this case it does actually work, but then the `taRight` alignment property on the `TPopupActionBar` is ignored. I gave up looking for a simple solution to that.)
3. Disable the button before calling `PopupMenu1.Popup()` but post a custom message to the form to re-enable it. Again this doesn't work - the posted message is unqueued ahead of the button click message for reasons I don't understand.*
4. Check that a threshold time has elapsed between `PopupMenu1.Popup()` returning and the next call to the button's `OnClick` handler. This works (on my system the threshold needs to be at least 60 msecs; I decided to use the double-click time) but this seems horrible, brittle, and wrong.

* I wonder whether this is because [posted messages are processed ahead of input messages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130531-00/?p=4203).

Comment: 5. Accept this default behavior?

Comment: I know it's not a solution but you can use Button1.Style:=bsSplitButton and set its DropDownMenu to PopupMenu1.

Comment: @NGLN I'm trying for the same effect as the Microsoft Edge More (...) dropdown menu. In my admittedly brief usability testing, *everyone* so far has tried to cancel the menu by pressing the button again.

Comment: And what about using CombBox with (or even without) custom draw list?

Comment: Very odd for a button to produce a menu?

Comment: @jano152 Interesting suggestion, but I think it would still look like a ComboBox, not a menu.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It seems to be becoming common, e.g. MS Edge, Firefox, Slack, Con-Emu (although it suffers from the cancel problem in this question),

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it is not so odd. As others said, it has become common in some applications, and it is common in e.g. OS X as well. There is (as someone also said) even a button style for a split button which has its own popup menu. So no, it is not very odd anymore.

Comment: @Rudy split button with a drop down makes sense. Plain TButton less so.

Comment: But isn't the "..." button in the Edge functionally more like a MainMenu? (I don't know I don't have Edge but it sounds like it could be.) If yes then it explains why are users expecting it to close the popup on the second click. So what about using MainMenu? Wouldn't that look and work like you need it to?

Comment: It is possible to [check if the popup menu is still open](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=958) in the OnClick handler. If so, don't open it again.

Comment: @David: yes, also plain buttons. Not so uncommon anymore, IME.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I've never seen it. Where should I be looking. If you want a menu to drop down when clicked, and then roll up when clicked again it should be a drop down button rather than a standard command button.

Comment: I have seen it several times, on different OSes, though (but including Windows), so it is not uncommon to me. Don't specifically ask me where. I don't write down such things.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis So not that common in other words. Thanks.

Comment: Not very common, but common enough not to be "very odd".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis By the time the OnClick handler executes the pop-up has already closed. That's the root of the problem.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Trying to detect that the popup menu is open using that code does not appear to yield anything useful. `IsMenuOpen` is always `False`.

Comment: Sorry folks - it's a duplicate. As so often, [Sertac Akyuz has the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27221422/127670).

Comment: I didn't have time to try it. But I see there is an answer already.